# PDF of normalized gaussian random vector

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

let $X$ be a Gaussian random vector in $R^n$ such that

$$X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I_n}),$$

How can I find the PDF of $\frac{X}{\|X\|}$?

Answer (score 1):

By rotation invariance / symmetry, the PDF is the uniform distribution on the unit sphere, so the PDF is the constant value $\frac{1}{S_{n-1}}$
where $S_{n-1} = \frac{n \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}$ is the [surface area of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Closed_forms).

Comment: sorry , Indeed I know this result ,however I can't  prove that .and I see some answer on this website but not quite get it .

Comment: What can be said when $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$?

Comment: @ShaoyuPei https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3120506/on-the-distribution-of-a-normalized-gaussian-vector

Comment: This doesn't seem to integrate to 1.