# Norm contrained Gaussian Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, geometric-probability

Let $X$ be a multivariate normal $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma^2)$ and let $X$ be anistropic, that is I am considering $\Sigma$ to be a diagonal matrix but the elements on the diagonal might be different.

I am interested in finding the distribution of $X/\|X\|_2$.

As a start for $X$ isotropic. Then $\|X\|_2^2$ will be Gamma Distributed. But then $\|X\|_2$ will perhaps have to follow what I found to be a Nakagami Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution). So I need to find a ratio of a normal and this nakagami distribution. However for the anisotropic case $\|X\|_2^2$ will not be gamma but a mixture of Gamma distributions (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/generic-sum-of-gamma-random-variables) and this seems more complicated to be honest.

On the other hand it feels intuitively to be somewhat similar to a truncated normal distribution but with the truncation happening over a unit ball and this also seems complicated.

Any ideas/ references/ hints/ thoghts

Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3120506/on-the-distribution-of-a-normalized-gaussian-vector